# Doctrine - I'm getting Entity class instead of Repository class

Tags: doctrine-orm, entity

I create instance of entity manager

```
$this->em = Connection::MainMySql()->GetEntityManager();
```

After some queries I try to get object from a Repository class.

```
$usersArray = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
                        ->select("us")
                        ->from('Model\Repo\mytables\User', "us")
                        ->where("us.idUser = :idUser")
                        ->setParameter("idUser", $idUser)
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->execute();
```

Why do I then get list of objects of class Model\Entity\mytables\User instead of Model\Repo\mytables\User even after I specify desired class in from(...) section?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, a repository cannot be used as a representation of a database entry.
In other words, Repositories should contain methods to retrieve/create/update/delete database entries represented by **entities**.

This is why the EntityManager is called **Entity** Manager, it manages Entities and not Repository classes.

For instance, you can perfectly do:

```
// Return an instance of the Repository Model\Repo\mytables\User
$repository = $this->em->getRepository('Model\Entity\mytables\User');

// The repository is used to create the QueryBuilder, so the from statement is already filled by doctrine as model\Entity\mytables\User
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
// ...
```

This is also why you can do:

```
$repository = $this->em->getRepository('Model\Entity\mytables\User');
// Return all entries of the 'users' table as Model\Entity\mytables\User instances
$users = $repository->findAll();
```

I'm surprised that the `from` statement of your query doesn't produce an error such as "Model\Entity\mytables\User is not a valid entity".

Also, your structure looks confusing, you must differentiate properly Repositories (the Models) from Entities in order to use them according to their respective roles.